# Angular 2 Fullversion, RouteSegment and RouteTree alternative?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, router

I try to Switch [this](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular2-CustomerManager) Angular App into a ASP.NET Core Angular 2 App, but I have a Problem with `RouteSegment` an `RouteTree`.

Follows the import:

```
Import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterSegment, OnActivate, RouteTree } from 'angluar2/router';
```

Follows the Router:

```
routerOnActivate(current: RouteSegment, prev?: RouteSegment,
    currTree?: RouteTree, prevTree?: RouteTree) {
    var path = currTree.children(current)[0].stringifiedUrlSegments;
    switch (path) {
      case 'details':
        this.displayMode = CustomerDisplayModeEnum.Details;
        break;
      case 'orders':
        this.displayMode = CustomerDisplayModeEnum.Orders;
        break;
      case 'edit':
        this.displayMode = CustomerDisplayModeEnum.Edit;
        break;
    }
  }
```

What is the alternative to RouteSegment and RouteTree?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? There `ActivatedRoute` that provides `parent` `firstChild`, and `children`.

Comment: My Problem is, that i update it to the fullversion of Angular 2 ('angular2/router') so the RouterSegment and the RouterTree does not work anymore, so the Segment/Tree do not exist in the fullversion.

Comment: The router in the final version works similarly (with some additional methods for convenience like `config`, `children`, `parent`, `firstChild`) but I don't know how to translate from old to new. If you inject `ActivatedRoute` you should be able to access parent and children from there.

Comment: i think that ActivatedRoute also does not exist in the final Version of Angular 2

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: thanks for your help